# ¿Diferencia entre fetch_object y fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, mysqli

Me tope con estas dos formas de manejar la info traída de la base de datos:

Una usando `fetch_object()`

```
while ($reg = $query -> fetch_object()) {

     echo "<option value=".$reg -> valor.">".$reg -> valor."</option>";
}
```

y la otra con `fetch_assoc()`

```
while ($reg = $query -> fetch_assoc()) {

    echo '<option value="'.$reg['valor'].'">'.$reg['valor'].'</option>';
}
```

¿Hay alguna ventaja en usar una manera sobre la otra?
¿O casos específicos donde usar una sea una mala practica?
Entre la información que encontré, se decía que eran prácticamente lo mismo.
Entonces, ¿Cuando uso una o cuando uso otra?

Comment: La diferencia es que `fetch_object` te crea un objeto con los resultados y `fetch_assoc` te crea un array asociativo. En cuanto usar una u otra es indiferente, simplemente, si necesitas un Objeto por algún motivo, usa la primera y si necesitas un array por algún motivo, usa la segunda. Alguna vez leí que la primera es ligeramente más lenta... pero eso pueden ser suposiciones, no recuerdo dónde lo leí y si no trabajas con varios cientos miles de datos o conexiones muy concurrentes esto debería tener muy poca importancia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La diferencia, como sin duda ya comprenderás, es que `fetch_object` te crea un objeto con los resultados y `fetch_assoc` te crea un array asociativo.

En cuanto usar una u otra es indiferente, simplemente, si por algún motivo necesitas trabajar con un objeto usa `fetch_object`, y si necesitas trabajar con array por algún motivo, usa `fetch_assoc`.

Otro aspecto que podría inclinar la balanza con respecto al uso de una u otra sería el rendimiento (sobre todo en contextos donde se manejen muchos datos o con mucha concurrencia o donde el uso de memoria/recursos sea muy determinante).

En SO en inglés existe [una pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328794/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-pdo-fetch-statements) al respecto, **pero se refiere a PDO**. Según algunas respuestas, en PDO obtener los resultados como objetos sería más lento en la mayoría de los casos, PERO **no tiene que ser así en mysqli**, pues son dos APIs totalmente distintas.

En cualquier caso, puedes elaborar tus propios benchmarks y si la diferencia es grande según tu contexto de uso, ya decidirás por una o por otra.